# scipy library error while importing train_test_split from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm applying this tutorial of [implementing recommendation system](https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/implementing-your-own-recommender-systems-in-Python/index.html) and I faced a problem when importing from sklearn.selection_model train_test_split in order to do the train/test split.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#create columns name
header = ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'timestamp']
#read data containing the full dataset of ratings
df = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', names=header)

n_users = df.user_id.unique().shape[0]
n_items = df.item_id.unique().shape[0]

print 'Number of users = ' + str(n_users) + ' | Number of movies = ' + str(n_items)
#train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df,test_size=0.25)

#print 'train shape = ' + str(train_data.shape)
```

Log error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/recommendation_system_trials/engine.py", line 3, in 
>       from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>     File "C:\Users\hello2\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 57, in 
>       from .base import clone
>     File "C:\Users\hello2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in 
>       from scipy import sparse
>   ImportError: No module named scipy

Why Am I getting this error, I'm not using scipy, I just wanted to import train_test_split.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `scipy` installed? You have to install it.

Comment: Why? what's the relation between?

Comment: It's a dependency of `sklearn`. Use `pip install scipy`.

Comment: How did you install scikit-learn? Using pip or any other method?

Comment: I installed it from the UI interface in PyCharm project settings. Trying to install scipy fails even with pip install scipy command

Comment: @SarahM  if you open your terminal console and type : python , does it recognize it ?

Comment: I used anaconda environment to solve the problem of scipy package.